# How to get sysdate value from oracle DB in django

Tags: django, sysdate

How to get sysdate value from oracle DB using django? I tried adding dual class in my model like below:

```
class Dual(models.Model):
dummy = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, blank=True)
sysdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'dual'
```

Tried accessing the sysdate:

```
sysdate = Dual.objects.only('sysdate')
```

but this result in below error:

> DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "DUAL"."SYSDATE": invalid identifier

Am i doing anything wrong? Please help me here.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve rows from the select statement with cursor iterator.
Especially you know that your get sysdate query will return exactly one row, so you can use fetchone() method.

views.py

```
from django.db import connection

def get_sysdate(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    sql = cursor.execute("select to_char(sysdate,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual")
    result = cursor.fetchone()

   return render(request, 'sysdate.html', {
        'result' : result,
    })
```

sysdate.html

```
{{ result }}
```

You can find related information below link.
[cx_Oracle - Fetch](https://dbaportal.eu/sidekicks/sidekick-cx_oracle-code-paterns/#part3.3)

Answer (score 0):

To access SQL function you can execute a custom query directly - [see the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).